# KDE resizes when I turn off a monitor

Tags: kubuntu, multiple-monitors, kde, xrandr

I have a fresh install of Kubuntu 14.04 with 3 monitors. When I turn off a monitor, KDE detects that and resizes/moves windows to the other monitors. I usually want to turn off all monitors and walk away.

I do NOT want this feature: when I come back to my desk and turn the monitors back on, the windows do not go back to the original monitor and KDE tends to crash (e.g. cannot access application launcher, task manager does not show windows, etc).

Does anyone know how to turn it off? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, Could you [edit] question and add output of `sudo lshw -c display` and `xrandr -q` . Are you switching off them physically using power buttons or soft tool like `xrandr`?